# Action_discovery_finish never being called

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am developing an application that needs to search Bluetooth devices when it is started. But the **ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED** is never called in my program, so it keeps discovering forever and I don't know why.
Here's my code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));
            if (checkBluetoothAdapter()) {
        finish();
    } else {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, 0);
    }
    search();
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    private int count;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                list.add(device);
                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Found: " + device.getName() + ": "
                                + device.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                count++;
            }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            count = 0;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Search started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
                .equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "Search finished. " + count + " devices found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
            updateList();
        }
    }
};

private void search() {
    if (btfAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        btfAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    btfAdapter.startDiscovery();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Searching",
            "Searching bluetooth devices...");
}
```

Comment: 1. what does checkBluetoothAdapter() do? and what does finish() do?
2. do you also call btfAdapter.getBondedDevices() ? because there might not be any devices that are discoverable but not already bonded when u r discovering...

Comment: checkBluetoothAdapter() only returns true or false depending on the getDefaultAdapter() return, and finish() finishes the activity

Comment: did u try uncoupling devices and then rediscover them?